# For loop of linear regression using filter to call specific rows

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, tidyverse, linear-regression

I have a data frame of different sites, year, and max temperature. I'd like to run a linear regression of the temp and year for each specific site. Instead of doing this for each site, it'd be nice if I could write a for loop that applies the same linear regression model to all of the sites individually and gives me an output with the name of the site in it. I've made some dummy data, I have 25 sites in the actual df.

```
data<- data.frame(site= c('alder','alder','alder','alder','alder','alder','alder','alder', 'oak','oak','oak','oak','oak','oak','oak','oak' ),
                  year= c('2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015','2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015'),
                  temp= c(0.5,3, 12, 42, 67, 8, 12, 22, 11, 4, 3, 6, 76, 1, 11, .9))
```

What here's how I've tried to do it so far:

```
output<- vector("list", length(unique(data$site)))

sites<- unique(data$site)

for (i in sites) {
  data %>% filter(site=i) =j
   lm(formula = temp~year, data = j)=k
  output[[i]]=k
  }
```

I'm not sure what the best way to make the for loop call the subset of rows that correspond to one site. When I run this code the error that I'm getting is

```
Error in data %>% filter(site = i) <- j : 
  could not find function "%>%<-"
```

I've already made sure tidyverse is in my library

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you use `=` for assignment as in `LHS = RHS` the value on the RHS is assigned to the name on the LHS. `x = 2` works, `2 = x` does not. You need to correct `data %>% filter(site=i) =j` to be `j = data %>% filter(site=i)` and `lm(formula = temp~year, data = j)=k` to `k = lm(formula = temp~year, data = j)`. Alternately you can use right-assignment with `->`, `2 -> x` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of typos, `=` would be `==` and do the `->` instead of `=`.  A third issue is the assignment to `[[i]]` - here `i` is each sites value.  Thus, we may need to name the `output` to get the correct assignment

```
names(output) <- sites
for (i in sites) {
  data %>% filter(site==i) -> j
   lm(formula = temp~year, data = j)-> k
  output[[i]]=k
  }
```

-output

```
> output
$alder

Call:
lm(formula = temp ~ year, data = j)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     year2009     year2010     year2011     year2012     year2013     year2014     year2015  
        0.5          2.5         11.5         41.5         66.5          7.5         11.5         21.5  


$oak

Call:
lm(formula = temp ~ year, data = j)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     year2009     year2010     year2011     year2012     year2013     year2014     year2015  
  1.100e+01   -7.000e+00   -8.000e+00   -5.000e+00    6.500e+01   -1.000e+01   -3.263e-15   -1.010e+01
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we may be able to do this a couple of ways

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
    nest_by(site) %>%
    mutate(model = list(lm(temp ~ year, data = data))) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  site                data model 
  <chr> <list<tibble[,2]>> <list>
1 alder            [8 × 2] <lm>  
2 oak              [8 × 2] <lm>
```

Or use `reframe` # dplyr version >= 1.1.0

```
data %>%
   reframe(model = list(lm(temp  ~year)), .by = site) %>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  site  model 
  <chr> <list>
1 alder <lm>  
2 oak   <lm>
```

Comment: Thank you! That first code with names() worked and did exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
lapply(split(data[, c("year", "temp")], data[, "site"]), 
       function(x) lm(temp ~ year, data=x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The data shown is too small to estimate sd's but assuming you actually have more data use `lmList`:

```
library(nlme) # comes with R so does not need to be installed

lmList(temp ~ year | site, data)
```

giving

```
Call:
  Model: temp ~ year | site 
   Data: data 

Coefficients:
      (Intercept) year2009 year2010 year2011 year2012 year2013      year2014 year2015
alder         0.5      2.5     11.5     41.5     66.5      7.5  1.150000e+01     21.5
oak          11.0     -7.0     -8.0     -5.0     65.0    -10.0 -3.263376e-15    -10.1

Error in pooledSD(x) : no degrees of freedom for estimating std. dev.
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an elegant solution but I'm not sure how to call the r-squared to determine how well it fits the data. Additionally I'm getting a single column for year in the result I'm assuming because that data is in the 'int' format. The result doesn't give me the summary table that @akrun's solution does which is useful for my purposes.

Comment: The result of `lmList` is a list of `lm` objects with class `lmList`.  If we call it `fm` then `sapply(fm, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)`   Try `methods(class = "lmList")` for more.  Also try `purrr::map_dfr(fm, broom::glance)`